I had a hot water heater installed; now the pressure in my upstairs bathroom sink is low both for the cold and hot faucets. What to do?
How to resolve low water pressure in upstairs sink after new hot water heater was installed.

Call the plumber back?

I would remove the sink's faucet aerator and clean the screens.
About the only way a hot water tank to change water pressure/flow is disturbing sediment and it collected at one point, the sink's aerator screen/s.
